# Is there a reduce function for python in which we can access index of current item?

Tags: python, reduce

```js
function namesScores(arr) {
  // Good luck!
  arr.sort();
  return arr.reduce((acc, v, i) => acc + wordWorth(v) * (i + 1), 0);
}
```

In the above code written in javascript the callable function that I have given to the reduce function uses three parameters accumulator, currentItem, currentIndex.

```py
from functools import reduce

def nameScores(arr):
    arr.sort()
    return reduce(lambda acc, v, i: acc + wordWorth(v) * (i + 1), arr, 0)
```

While writing the same code in python, I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cyogian/practicePython/ProjectEuler/p022/p022.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(nameScores(test1))
  File "/home/cyogian/practicePython/ProjectEuler/p022/p022.py", line 18, in nameScores
    return reduce(lambda acc, v, i: acc + wordWorth(v) * (i + 1), arr, 0)
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'
```

This says that the currentIndex parameter is missing. Is it that the reduce function in python functools does not give access to the currentIndex?

Is there any other version of reduce in python that give access to the index of current item in the iterable?

Or should I go with simple forLoop in the case where I need access to Index?

Answer (score 9):

You don't need a special form of `reduce` to access the index: just use the `enumerate` function on the iterable you want to reduce.

```py
>>> a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda acc, iv: acc + str(iv[0]) + iv[1], enumerate(a), '')
'0foo1bar2baz'
```

Here, `iv` is one pair from `enumerate`, so `iv[0]` is the index and `iv[1]` is the value.

---

### Explanation:

The `reduce` function in Python indeed does not pass the index to the callback. The Javascript `Array.reduce` method does, and can get away with this because if you pass more arguments than a Javascript function expects, they are just ignored; so your callback function in Javascript can be like `(acc, v) => acc + v` and it will ignore the index when it's called with `(acc, v, i)` as its arguments.

Python functions don't silently ignore extra arguments; if you call a function in Python with too many arguments, it raises a `TypeError`. This means if `reduce` called your callback function with the arguments `(acc, v, i)`, then you would be *required* to provide a callback function which accepts the index, even though in the vast majority of cases, you don't need to use the index for anything. That is, if you could ever call `reduce(lambda acc, v, i: ..., ..., ...)` where the callback takes three arguments, then you would *always* have to call `reduce` like that in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation on why it is not possible in python. Now I understand, probably I will go with a for loop instead of using reduce.